# Converting Bitmap into base64 string and saving in Shared Preference

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, sharedpreferences

In my onCreate method, i have a bitmap image (transferred from another activity).

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapClothes");
```

Below my onCreate method, i wrote a method to convert my bitmap into base64 string.

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("Image log:", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
};
```

Finally, my method to save in shared preferences:

```
public void savepic (View view){
    SharedPreferences mypreference = getSharedPreferences("image", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Pic1 = "image1";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreference.edit();
    editor.putString("Pic1",encodeToBase64(bitmap));
    editor.commit();
};
```

However, in the following line below, it can't seems to read my bitmap variable (cannot resolve symbol bitmap). i really habe no idea what to do... Any help is greatly appreciated~

```
editor.putString("Pic1",encodeToBase64(bitmap));
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just saving it as an image file?

Comment: Bad implementation. Save the image in app private folder and store the path to image in shared preference.

Comment: @MikeM. if i want to save locally in the app, i can't just save as image file from what i researched.

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that, but it's not true. Calling `openFileOutput()` on a `Context` will return a `FileOutputStream` you can use to write any kind of file you want to your app's internal storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done the same thing in my project.

**Bitmap Conversion and Storing into Shared Preference**

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapClothes");                    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    myPrefsEdit.putString("url", temp);
    myPrefsEdit.commit();
```

**Retrieving from Shared Preference and Loading it into an ImageView**

```
String temp = myPrefs.getString("url", "defaultString");
        try {
            byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(temp, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: That was the perfect answer to my problem! Thank you!